# Keeping multiple types ( nesting types / embedding types ) in a single collection:

Tags: graphql, faunadb

I want to keep all of the types in a single collection named “BenchmarkDatasets”. Do I need to declare the subtypes(LatData, AggregateData, MetaData) differently or do I just need to accept that I’ll have a collection for every type?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the Schema I [generated](https://walmartlabs.github.io/json-to-simple-graphql-schema/):

```
type LatData {
    LatResults: [[Int ]] 
    LatResultSize: [Int ] 
}

type AggregateData { 
    EVRCounter: Int
    EVRLatencyTotal: Int
    EVRLatencyAverage: Float
    LatTestCount: Int
    LatencyTotal: Int
    LatencyAverage: Float 
}

type MetaData { 
    StartTimeUTC: String
    EndTimeUTC: String
    StartTimeLocal: String
    EndTimeLocal: String 
}

type BenchmarkDataset { 
    LatData: LatData
    AggregateData: AggregateData
    MetaData: MetaData
}

type Query {
  allBenchmarkDatasets: [BenchmarkDataset!]
}
```

And here's the data I want to shove into "BenchmarkDatasets":

```
    {
        "MetaData" : 
            {
                "StartTimeUTC" : "Sun Oct 18 21:41:38 2020\n",
                "EndTimeUTC" : "Sun Oct 18 21:45:38 2020\n",
                "StartTimeLocal" : "Sun Oct 18 16:41:38 2020\n",
                "EndTimeLocal" : "Sun Oct 18 16:45:38 2020\n"
            },
            "AggregateData" : 
            {
                "EVRCounter" : 3,
                "EVRLatencyTotal" : 70,
                "EVRLatencyAverage" : 23.333333333333332,
                "LatTestCount" : 159,
                "LatencyTotal" : 11871,
                "LatencyAverage" : 74.660377358490564
            },
            "LatData" : 
            {
                "LatResultSize" : 
                [
                    4,
                    4,
                    4
                ],
                "LatResults" : 
                [
                    [
                        0,
                        2,
                        "zoom",
                        "latencymonitor"
                    ],
                    [
                        1,
                        1,
                        "zoom",
                        "latencymonitor"
                    ],
                    [
                        2,
                        1,
                        "zoom",
                        "latencymonitor"
                    ],
                    [
                        3,
                        1,
                        "dota2",
                        "dota2"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
```

Also, I know that my data is not well formatted(specifically the 2d "LatData" array that contains 2 ints and 2 strings), and any data format tips are also appreciated.

Comment: input types are not for that ... it's only a kind of data type used for mutations ... f.e. without id field created on DB insert ... bad syntax/usage ... search for some, general graphql tutorial

Comment: I re-worded the question and sample code/data to be much more concise. Does that make any more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue! I specifically needed  to use the "[@embedded](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/directives/d_embedded)" directive to make my schema look something like this:

```
type LatData @embedded {
    LatResults: [[Int ]] 
    LatResultSize: [Int ] 
}

type AggregateData @embedded { 
    EVRCounter: Int
    EVRLatencyTotal: Int
    EVRLatencyAverage: Float
    LatTestCount: Int
    LatencyTotal: Int
    LatencyAverage: Float 
}

type MetaData @embedded { 
    StartTimeUTC: String
    EndTimeUTC: String
    StartTimeLocal: String
    EndTimeLocal: String 
}

type BenchmarkDataset { 
    LatData: LatData
    AggregateData: AggregateData
    MetaData: MetaData
}

type Query {
  allBenchmarkDatasets: [BenchmarkDataset!]
}
```